# Postgresql: Edit pg_hba.conf to allow trust authorization temporarily

Tags: database, postgresql

I Forgot my postgres password so I can't connect to the DB, I found those steps :

```
1. edit pg_hba.conf to allow trust authorization temporarily
 2. Reload the config file (pg_ctl reload)
 3. Connect and issue ALTER ROLE / PASSWORD to set the new password
 4. edit pg_hba.conf again and restore the previous settings
 5. Reload the config file again
```

I'm trying to follow but I'm stuck at step one. 
What should I change in pg_hba.conf to allow trust authorization temporarily.

Comment: Use "trust" instead of md5 or any other authentication method. Please check the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Yes I changed the file config, reload the conf, changed the passwd ... same error Authentification failed for user postgres

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Please show us both your pg_hba.conf files and your connection string to connect with the database that results in the authentication error.

Comment: I found out that I forgot to add a semicolon at the end of the command to Alter the user. Alter user postgres with password 'postgres';